# Css and styles not working on html page with cgi-bin

Tags: html, css, cgi-bin

If i address the html file directly , all looks fine, styles are applied and background is there.

if  the page is addressed by cgi-bin , no styles are apllied, even the background image is not shown .

why ?

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Foutmelding</title>
<link href="../styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     media="screen" />

</head>
<body style="background-image:url('../images/comp01.png')">
De ingevulde gegevens zijn niet correct. Gelieve opnieuw te proberen.<p>Hou 
rekening met het volgende:</p>
<ul>
    <li>de velden met een <font color="#CC0000">*</font> zijn verplicht</li>
    <li>de postcode mag enkel cijfers bevatten, en enkel tussen 1000 </li>  <li>naam, voornaam en woonplaats mogen enkel letters bevatten.</li>
</ul>
<p>Volgende gegevens werden geregistreerd:</p>
<ul>
    <li><b>Naam</b><font color="#CC0000">*</font><b>:</b> $in{naam}</li>
    <li><b>Voornaam</b>*<b>:</b> $in{voornaam} </li>
    <li><b>Postcode</b><b>:</b> $in{postcode}</li>
    <li><b>Woonplaats</b><b>:</b> $in{woonplaats}</li>
    <li><b>Telefoonnummer:</b> $in{telefoon}</li>
    <li><b>E-mailadres:</b> $in{MAILFROM}</li>
    <li><b>Onderwerp</b><b>:</b> $in{SUBJECT}</li>
    <li><b>Omschrijving</b><b>:</b> $in{omschrijving}</li>
</ul>
<p><a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Klik hier</a> om opnieuw</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the URL-paths you use to access the page a) directly and b) via cgi?

Comment: Are you sure assets are in parent dir than the current site? `../images`, `../styles`

Comment: <form name="contact" action="/cgi-bin/form.cgi"   onsubmit="return validateForm()"  method="POST">

Comment: the /images and  /styles folder are in the parent directory

Comment: i think you're right, it's got something to do with the directory !  thanks